# Not able to update SQLite data from Thread

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, xamarin, threadpool

I've got some code that is working as expected.

```
public class PlayCommand: IPlayCommand {

    // this code works but `_userService.GetById()` and `_userService.Save()` lock the UI.
    public void Execute(object parameter) {
        var vm = (HomeFragmentViewModel) parameter;

        // first hit on the database 
        var user = _userService.GetById(Mvx.Resolve < UserModel > ().Id);

        user.PlayPositions.First(p = > p.ChapterId == vm.UserPlayPosition.ChapterId).PlayPosition = _audioPlayer.CurrentPosition;

        // second hit on the database.
        _userService.Save(user);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that if I try to off load the work from the UI layer in order to speed up performance, the user doesn't get saved.

```
// Even though I can see all lines executing, the database doesn't get updated
// when using this approach.
public void Execute(object parameter) {

    var vm = (HomeFragmentViewModel)parameter;

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o = > UpdateUserPlayPosition(vm));

    // also tried
    // new Task(() => UpdateUsersCurrentChapter(vm)).Start();

}

private void UpdateUserPlayPosition(HomeFragmentViewModel vm)
{
    var user = _userService.GetById(Mvx.Resolve<UserModel>().Id);

    user.PlayPositions.First(p => p.ChapterId == vm.UserPlayPosition.ChapterId).PlayPosition = _audioPlayer.CurrentPosition;

    // execute a new task to save the user back to the local database
    _userService.Save(user);
}
```

Next time I ask the database for `CurrentPosition`, it's still set to the original value (0).

I also notice a lot of the following in the debug output.

```
01-13 13:31:57.242 E/SQLiteLog(16542): (1) statement aborts at 2: [ROLLBACK] cannot rollback - no transaction is active
```

I did try setting SQLite to  MultiThread it in the config in the Constructor of my ConnectionProvider but then it throws a different exception as soon as I try to hit the DB for the first time.

```
public class DbConnectionProvider : IDbConnectionProvider
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbConnectionProvider(string sqliteDatabasePath)
    {
        _connectionString = "Data Source=" + sqliteDatabasePath;
        SqliteConnection.SetConfig(SQLiteConfig.MultiThread);
    }

    public SqliteConnection GetOpenConnection()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection(_connectionString);
        if (connection == null) throw new Exception("Could not create a database connection.");

        connection.Open();

        return connection;
    }
}
```

```
01-18 13:33:31.278 E/mono    (21714): System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: Library used incorrectly
01-18 13:33:31.278 E/mono    (21714):   at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.SetConfig (SQLiteConfig config) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I'm using `Mono.Data.Sqlite` **v2.0.5.0** as the backend to my DbProvider.

Comment: I'm open to using some other (read better) approach over `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: You should really be using the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx), it's much more flexible.

Comment: @James is that really going to make any difference? I tried a regular `Task` as well as `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and both of them yielded the same results... which is not saving data to Sqlite.

Comment: that was more of a general comment as TPL has a lot of benefits over the ThreadPool. As to your problem, what SQLite lib are you using? Does it not already async support? I am using [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) which has an asynchronous API (it utilises the TPL also).

Comment: We're using Mono.Data.Sqlite v2.0.5.0

Comment: According to the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) the database will run in serialised mode if `SQLITE_THREADSAFE` is not explicitly set so this should work out the box, however, it's worth checking that this isn't set to 0.

Comment: That message correlates with the `SQLITE_MISUSE` error, from the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/c_interface.html) - *"Examples of incorrect usage include calling **sqlite_exec** after the database has been closed using **sqlite_close** or calling **sqlite_exec** with the same database pointer simultaneously from two separate threads"* - I would add some traceability into your app, sounds like there are 2 threads trying to hit the DB from different threads which `MultiThread` mode doesn't allow.